# Neo4j Multiple Relationship combine

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a Cypher file which creates hundreds of different types of Nodes all with unique Labels

Here is an example of each type I have created :

```
CREATE (G1034:Rooms{Name:"G1034"})
CREATE (GroupA:Groups{Name:"GroupA"})
CREATE (Donald:Lecturers{Name:"Donald"})
CREATE (Monday:Days{Name:"Monday"})
CREATE (Slot1:Times{Name:"9am-10Am"})
CREATE (FinalYearProject:Module{Name:"Final Year Project"})
```

what I was trying to do is create a Relationship between them like a timetable slot

```
 CREATE
 (Donald)-[:TEACHES]->(FinalYearProject)-[:To]->(GroupA)-[:IN]->(G1034)-[:AT]->(Slot1)-[:ON]->(Monday)
```

but it doesn't seem to be right syntax I have.I am new to Neo4j  and have searched the internet for a solution but most examples have like two nodes related at most.

does anyone know is there a way to create a relationship like this and if so is there a way to do this

any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You miss the concept of the "Lesson" or "Event"

If you want to create these relationships later, find your nodes first, then create the connecting relationship. There is a good discussion in the (free) "[GraphDatabases](http://graphdatabases.com)" Book about those "Event"/"Message" nodes.

```
MATCH (G1034:Rooms{Name:"G1034"})
MATCH (GroupA:Groups{Name:"GroupA"})
MATCH (Donald:Lecturers{Name:"Donald"})
MATCH (Monday:Days{Name:"Monday"})
MATCH (Slot1:Times{Name:"9am-10Am"})
MATCH (FinalYearProject:Module{Name:"Final Year Project"})

CREATE (lesson:Lesson)

CREATE
 (Donald)-[:TEACHES]->(lesson),
 (lesson)-[:TO]->(GroupA),
 (lesson)-[:IN]->(G1034),
 (lesson)-[:AT]->(Slot1),
 (lesson)-[:ON]->(Monday)
 (lesson)-[:FOR]->(FinalYearProject)
```